# Should I use Blob storage or Azure VM storage for files?

Tags: transactions, asp.net-mvc-5, storage, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application that is being stored on an Azure VM. In this internet application, user can upload files such as images and videos that can be accessed by the public via a url.

My question is this:

Should I store this uploaded data in a Azure Block Blob container within the same location as the Azure VM, or let the users upload this data to the VM storage's hard drive, that can then be accessed via a url?

Is it be cheaper to use Blob storage, or store files on a VM?

For example, if I had the following files stored on Blob storage, and on an Azure VM, and each is accessed and viewed 100 times, what would be cheaper?

1. 10 * 1MB images
2. 10 * 5MB videos

Also, other than the cost of storage and transaction cost, what other factors should I take into consideration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it seems you should create a separate container for the uploaded blobs and mark it public. Your app should save the user uploaded files to this public container. Then users can access the files from the container directly through the blob's URL.

There are a few reasons for this recommendation:

1. Cost: As you mention, the cost for a block blob is cheaper than space on VHD
2. IOPS: Your VHD has a limit of 500 IO operations per second. You are already running your app and OS on this VHD, meaning all your uploaded files combined have less IOPS remaining
3. Throughput: By serving these blobs through storage directly, you are nt making your front-end VM be the bandwidth bottleneck (VM's network can get saturated if the download traffic is high)
4. Manageability: You can manage the blobs from any explorer and add/remove manually with any storage explorer, without having to log in to your VM to do it.
5. Scalability: If you put it on the VM's disk, then just that one VM has access to the files. With blobs, you can use multiple VMs as front-ends to scale out as your load increases.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear.. Premium Storage is not ideal for the workload described in the original email.  Premium Storage is specifically designed for Azure Virtual Machine workloads requiring guarantee IOPS and low latency such as database applications.  Cost will be higher than storing the data in the block blob.  Block Blobs are also more appropriate for media file serving.

Answer (score 0):

All Azure VMS have at least two disks when you first provision a VM - an OS disk and a temporary disk.

You do not store data on the temporary disk as it is solely for temporary storage; the data on that drive will be lost when the VM is moved to another physical machine, which can happen during upgrades, patches, and when Windows Azure detects something is wrong with the node you are running on. I would also not recommend storing data on the OS disk.  Both OS and temporary disks have a maximum size and you will hit the maximum size limit as your data size grows.

I do not know your exact requirements, but it seems to me that you will want to use Azure Blob Storage or attach more data drives to your VM and persist the data there.

Comment: How about cost though? If I have a lot of space on the VM, is it cheaper to use Blob storage or the VM's hard drive with the data in the post?

Comment: When you said you have a lot of space on the VM, which disk are you referring to? Are you referring to a temp disk where you should not store your persistent data? As for the cost, you can look the block blob storage pricing @ http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/.  Azure Block Blob pricing for locally redundant storage is at $0.024/GB/Month plus transaction fees so 60 MB of data should not cost you a whole lot but you control your budget so you know better.  I would consider availability, scalability and durability requirements first and then factor in the cost.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use blob storage to store Your files. Atul Sikaria pointed to pros and cons, but we also need to remember, that there is an option to use Premium storage with SSD disks. It is very efficient option comparing to standard blob storage.